# TypeError: _this.child(key).get is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state-management

I'm using [hookstate](https://hookstate.js.org/) to import an array which is going to be stored in state.

I've got this initial object -
import { createState } from "@hookstate/core";

```
const initialState = {
    exerciseDetails: [
        {
            exerciseID: 1,
            exerciseName: "ex name",
            exerciseDesc: "desc",
        },
    ],
};

const exerciseState = createState(initialState);
export default exerciseState;
```

And then I'm accessing the object in my functional component as -

```
function CreateWorkoutScreen(){
    const global = useState(exerciseState);
    const { exerciseDetails } = global.get();
}
```

Which gives me the following error - `TypeError: _this.child(key).get is not a function. (In '_this.child(key).get()', '_this.child(key).get' is undefined)`

However, if I change my initial state to

```
const initialState = {
        count: 0,
};
```

and access it in my functional component as

```
  function CreateWorkoutScreen(){
    const global = useState(exerciseState);
    const { count } = global.get();
}
```

It works as expected. I'm guessing I'm not getting access to the array properly? Am I using the wrong syntax here?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have not imported `useState` from `@hookstate/core`, but from `React`

```js
const global = useState(exerciseState); //define global state locally with hookstate's useState method
const { exerciseDetails } = global.get();

const accessFunction = () => {
  const type1 = global.exerciseDetails.get(); //works
  const type2 = global["exerciseDetails"].get(); //works
  //const type3 = global[exerciseDetails].get(); //error
  const { exerciseDetails } = global.get(); //works
  return [exerciseDetails, type1, type2];
};
```

Also here is the working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-field-vjp61?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for contributing. SO format differs slightly from traditional forums. Here are some requirements you may not be aware of. Please edit to also embed your working example into the post. Links are welcome, but important info from links must also be embedded, as the post becomes useless if the page is unreachable, or the content changes, & nobody should be required to go clicking to find a promised answer (though options are nice). SO Answers should contain exact code necessary to solve OP's issue, & an explanation as to how/why key bits of your solution addresses OP's issue.